# WebApi POST method with string parameter is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST method in my WebApi that takes json string as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]  
public HttpResponseMessage GetOrderDataBySessionId([FromBody] string json)
```

I tried hitting it using RestClient with URL: **localhost:56934/api/Home/GetOrderDataBySessionId**

and specifying following json string in the Body:

```
{
  "ListSessionId": [
    "180416073256DGQR10",
    "180416091511DGQR10"
  ]
}
```

setting the body/content type as **application/json**. But when it hits my method, the `json` string parameter is always null.

Is it because I need to use a complex type in parameter?

Can we never have input in string?

Comment: If you expect a string, format it as one in the body. Now you are sending a json object, not a string.

Comment: That is not a string you are sending it's an object, use this for a string "{
  \"ListSessionId\": [
    \"180416073256DGQR10\",
    \"180416091511DGQR10\"
  ]
}"

Comment: @AdeoluwaSimeon Now I know what I was doing wrong.Thanks, Works now :)

Answer (score 2):

By sending this content:

```
{
  "ListSessionId": [
    "180416073256DGQR10",
    "180416091511DGQR10"
  ]
}
```

You're sending a JSON represented with a proprerty `ListSessionId` typed as an array of string so your Web API action should be:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetOrderDataBySessionId([FromBody] List<string> listSessionId)
```

Just change the `string json` to `List<string> listSessionId`.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem.

Code in client:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/api",
            type: "post",
            data: "p1=1&p2=2"
        });
```

code in server:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromForm] string p1, [FromForm] string p2)
{
    return p1+p2;
}
```

There are three key points:

1. The parameter name must be the same both in client and server.
2. In the client, there must be `[FromForm]` instead of `[FromBody]` in front
   of the parameter.
3. You can add multiple parameters even, but the parameter names must correspond.